# How do I get typo3 running

Tags: typo3

I am a complete newbie in typo3 and I hope someone can find time to guide me to get my installation running. Going through the getting started page, I untarred

```
typo3_src-7.6.10.tar.gz"
```

in

```
/var/www/html
```

on Linux (Ubuntu). At this step am stuck. I have also created the recommended links in htdocs contained in my rootdocument, which I named "weaconsort". I have even created an empty file "FIRST_INSTALL". Below are contents of htdocs:

```
FIRST_INSTALL
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13363 Aug 10 19:30 .htaccess
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    19 Aug 10 19:29 index.php -> typo3_src/index.php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    15 Aug 10 19:30 typo3 -> typo3_src/typo3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    19 Aug 10 19:29 typo3_src -> ../typo3_src-7.6.10
```

At this point am stuck. How do I launch typo3 to start the configuration?
Thanks to comments I have received so far I have made some progress. I am able to open my page in a browser. According to the tpyo3 documentation if I put

```
http://localhost/mypage/typo3/install
```

I should be taken through the configuration for the backend. But I do not see any file named install in the typo3 directory. When I put

```
http://localhost/weaconsort/typo3_src-7.6.10/typo3/sysext/backend/
```

I see typo3 directories as shown in the picture attached.[image: typo3 directories]. My problem still remains- how do I login to the backend?

Sorry to come back on the same issue. After a lot of trying, I do not understand why I cannot get the install tool. From this site

```
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/QuickInstall/TheInstallTool/Index.html
```

when I enter

```
http://www.example.com/typo3/install/
```

I get a short paragraph with the title "Example Domain". I am able to read all my documents with "localhost/domainname/docname", but its more like only on the frontend.
The one install file I see in typo3 is in "typo3_src-7.6.10/typo3/sysext/install/Start/" (install.php). When I put this in my web browser I get

```
run(); });
```

I have gone read the installguide over and over, can't figure out what am not doing correctly. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you opened it in a browser?

Comment: Apparently one of your TYPO3 PHP files has an error or your last FTP process for copying TYPO3 to your server did fail. Retry it with new TYPO3 files again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are just missing to call the url in your Webbrowser. By guessing this is just localhost in your case

Comment: Thanks @Ringer. When I put loclhost in the web browser I get the apache2 page which shows apache is properly installed and works. My typo3 on Windows was installed through Windowsinstaller and has got a file named typo3start.exe which when executed shows apache is running and mysql in running then I can start typo3. I am able to login as typo3, pwd:typo3. I messed up the amin password and can no longer login as admin. That is why I want to work in Linux. My problem is: How do I start typo3 in Linux?

Comment: Check out the vhost config then about the default path and move the TYPO3 installation there. There is nothing to start like your windowsinstaller did.

Comment: Locate vhost shows me a lot of locations with vhost directories and header files (.h). The vhosts.conf I have looked at is in /usr/local/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf. Do I move my root typo3 installation to  /usr/local/conf/extra/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to start anything. If your web server is running, typo3 is running. Now, like Georg Ringer said, you just have to call typo3 to finish the installation.

Since you said that localhost give you a php_info(), then most likely you have to type localhost/html/typo3.

I would have commented but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out from the recommendations above. First let me restate my issue. I have my webpage which I want to develop in line with typo3 standard. I have now moved my files to "/var/www/html/weaconsort/htdocs". In the web browser I enter "localhost//var/www/html/weaconsort/htdocs/index.html" in the hope that my index file will open. I get the "NOT FOUND" message. how do I go forward

Comment: If you move all your file to that location and didn't add a new file called index.html, that's normal since the index from typo3 is a php file, not a html one. Normally, "localhost//var/www/html/weaconsort/htdocs/" should be enough. If that doesn't work, rename "index.php" to something else and create a new one with a echo inside. If you can't see your message, that means that the problem come from your web server.

Comment: Thanks @ Stéphane Pelletier, am making progress. I moved my index.html to my document root (i.e the hostname=http://localhost/weaconsort/index.html). My browser can now read index.html. Infact the error was putting the whole path following localhost, i.e. from /var..., instead of localhost/domainname.

Comment: Perfect! If you can read your index.html file, do your symbolic links for typo3 in the same folder the same way you did before. You should be able to do localhost/weaconsort/typo3 and it should let you finalize your installation.

Comment: This last comment @stephane is right on. I think there is an error in the way I installed. What am trying to do is to uninstall and start all over. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a `composer install` in the root of your install? If no `composer.json` is found there, try to do a `composer install` in the `typo3-folder` as this loads the needed dependencies.