# how does one get the typo3 install tool?

Tags: typo3

After not being able to get answer to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883035/how-do-i-get-typo3-running),
for me to go forward maybe I can ask my question this way:
I have set up my typo3 installation and am able to read my files at

```
localhost/mydomain
```

According to the installguide, entering

```
http://www.example.com/typo3/install
```

is supposed to guide me to complete the configuration of typo3. For my case entering the above link opens me an example page. As things tand I can only read my documents on the frontend.
The assistance am seeking is, how do I get the install tool to finish my configuration so that I can access the backend?

Answer (score -1):

```
http://localhost/mydomain/typo3/install
```

It looks like you don't know how a web server works and how to access your ressources, so i would advise that you read a guide about it first

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri, if you know I document from which I can start, I would appreciate, otherwise I will google for "how a web server works.

Comment: I have found one reference here https://sites.duke.edu/workblog/files/2014/12/www.dedoimedo.com-apache-web-server-lm.pdf which it appears will sort out my problem.

Comment: You are welcome. It would be best to read the documentation of the server you have installed. If you are running on windows, then it could be a XAMP installation?